# Why does this not print everything on the same line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

watch this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFdP3_TF7Ks) from 2:47 you will understand my predicament.

It is supposed to print backwards on the same line.

```
namespace UnderstandingArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
        string zig = "You can get what you want out of life if "
            + "you help enough people get what they want out of life.";

        char[] charArray = zig.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);

        foreach (char zigChar in charArray)
        {
            Console.Write(zigChar);    
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a curly bracket missing. Shouldn't there be one after `Console.Write(zigChar);`?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the output that are getting that you think is incorrect?

Comment: I figured it out. I had curly brackets after the foreach. Somehow that caused it to print each character vertically instead of in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadLine() blocks until your program reads a '\n', so your program prints out a single character and waits for you to hit Enter (which causes your terminal to go to the next line). Because of this, you end up getting a single character on each line.

You could use [Console.ReadKey(Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx) to get (and not display) the next keystroke.

You can also move [Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) outside your foreach loop, so that it prints everything and then waits for a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had curly brackets after the foreach. Somehow that caused it to print each character vertically instead of in one line.